# The X-XSS-Protection header is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, apache, security, xss

I just added these 2 line to my server code

```
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header('x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block');
```

I scan my site using Nikto, still seeing these as issues.

```
- Nikto v2.1.6
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Target Port:        443
+ Start Time:         2020-01-18 14:54:02 (GMT-5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Server: cloudflare
+ The X-XSS-Protection header is not defined. This header can hint to the user agent to protect against some forms of XSS
+ The X-Content-Type-Options header is not set. This could allow the user agent to render the content of the site in a different fashion to the MIME type
```

These 2 errors

> - The X-XSS-Protection header is not defined. This header can hint to the user agent to protect against some forms of XSS
> - The X-Content-Type-Options header is not set. This could allow the user agent to render the content of the site in a different fashion to the MIME type

Is it a false report ? or my syntax wrong

---

## Update

```
⚡️  Desktop  curl -I app.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 18 Jan 2020 20:17:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=de78c7d75c4277a60649fb1d63d00ac531579378646; expires=Mon, 17-Feb-20 20:17:26 GMT; path=/; domain=.app.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Location: https://app.com/
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5573409b9a45f051-EWR
```

Comment: Perhaps your scan is receiving a cached response.

Comment: How do we make sure that not happening ?

Comment: Is there a way to clear cache off my server ?

Comment: What does `curl -I URL` return for you?

Comment: let me try that now.

Comment: `CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC` I got this.

Comment: You are hitting a redirect, follow the `location` to see the relevant headers (e.g. `curl -I https://app.com/`. Looks like you are using CF for CDN as well so might need to purge the cache there, and/or use a `worker` to make sure headers cache correctly.

Comment: Let me try to purge the cache there. Thanks.

Comment: I went to CF, purge everything. Wait 30 seconds, rescan twice. same result.

Comment: If you guys have nikto on your machine, feel free to try `nikto -h https://awsri.com`

Comment: I just dbcheck my server, I have that 2 line there : https://i.imgur.com/7LUNiTe.png